# Построение трехмерного графика Зонтик Уитни

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

U = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1)
V = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1)

X = np.dot(U, V)
Y = U
Z = np.dot(V, V)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

Я впервые в жизни строю трехмерные графики, по заданию нужен график Зонтик Уитни. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не получается и как сделать наилучшим образом?

Comment: dot - это скалярное произведение, насколько я помню, результатом такого произведения будет скаляр, т.е. просто число. А plot_surface последним аргументом хочет получить двумерный объект, т.е. матрицу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неверно используете методы linspace и dot. Без явного указания имени параметра, третий аргумент в linspace у вас воспринимается как количество делений, а не шаг. Про dot вам написали в комментариях - вам нужно разобраться с методом meshgrid. Например так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

U = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
V = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(U, V)
Z = (np.ravel(Y)**2).reshape(X.shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это, разумеется, не зонтик Уитни, но для иллюстрации построения 3д-поверхности подойдет

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

u = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
v = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)
X=U*V
Y=U
Z = V*V

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

результат:

[image: зонтик Уитни]

Comment: я-то плюсанул ответ, хотя сам намеренно не давал готового решения, чтобы автор вопроса чуть-чуть подумал сам, как вывести параметрическую поверхность.